# Algorithms behind the z3 solver

Tags: algorithm, z3, solver, smt, sat

I just learned about [DPLL(T)](https://www.lsi.upc.edu/~oliveras/espai/papers/cav04-slides.pdf) and the [DPLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm) in relation to SMT solvers. I have seen [z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) referenced in a few places regarding SMT solvers as well.

Wondering what the z3 uses for its algorithms at a high level for implementing the SMT solving. If it is DPLL algorithms, a variation, something custom, a bunch of things, etc. Hoping to learn about the different types of algorithms a modern SMT solver uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMT solvers come from a long line of research in automated reasoning, both in computer-based theorem-proving communities and in traditional mathematical logic. It's impossible to summarize all the algorithms/research in a stack-overflow answer. However, the book http://www.decision-procedures.org/ is an excellent read, and have many references that can help you guide into the literature. (The first edition is already 10 years old, but I see now that they have a second edition that came out in 2016.)

Comment: Thank you very much, that is all I needed. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can check the following link where it says what algorithms are used in Z3 and many more stuff. For example in section 6.5 you can see that they use NLSAT algorithm for nonlinear real arithmetic theory parts.
[https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html)